# Getting cost and hours for each order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having following six tables :

**EMPLOYEE**

```
PK: employeeID;     
FK: empBranch references BRANCH;
FK: empSupervisor references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

**CUSTOMER**

```
PK: customerID
```

[image]

**ORDERS**

```
PK: orderNumber
FK: customerID references CUSTOMER; 
FK: salesPerson references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

**PRODUCT**

```
PK: productCode
```

[image]

**PRODLINE**

```
PK: orderNumber + prodCode
FK: orderNumber references ORDERS;
FK: prodCode references PRODUCT
```

[image]

**INSTLINE**

```
PK: orderNumber + instType
FK: orderNumber references ORDERS; 
FK: instType refesnrences INSTALLATION
```

[image]

I was making a project and got stuck in between. Can someone help me how to list out for each Order the OrderNumber, orderdate, EmployeeID of salesperson, total amount for products, and total amount for installation. The total amount for products is the sum of the unit price times quantity of the products ordered. The total amount for installation is the sum of number of hours times the billing rate of the installation types.
I was trying to make query for it since two hours.Please help

Solution to above part as mentioned in answer

```
Select o.ORDERNUMBER, ORDERDATE, SALESPERSON, 
SUM (PRICE * QUANTITY) as TOTALPRODUCTAMOUNT, 
SUM (HOURS * RATE) as TOTALINSTALLCOST 
from ORDERS o 
join PRODLINE pl on pl. ORDERNUMBER = o. ORDERNUMBER
join PRODUCT p on p.PRODUCTCODE = pl. PRODUCTCODE
join INSTLINE il on il. ORDERNUMBER = o. ORDERNUMBER
join INSTALLATION i on i.INSTALLTYPE = il.INSTTYPE
group by o. ORDERNUMBER, ORDERDATE, SALESPERSON;
```

**EDIT :** 
Assuming The total amount of an order is given by the sum of TOTALPRODUCTAMOUNT and TOTALINSTALLCOST. The revenue_generated by a branch is the sum of the total amount of all orders for salespersons working at that branch. So we need to figure out the branch number, branch name, revenue_target, and the revenue_generated for each branch that fails to meet its revenue_target.

We can assume Branch table to be as follow :

[image]

Comment: What query you tried?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @vol7ron There is no homework tag here and neither its any homework

Comment: The point is how to ask a question.  "[Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"  You can remove *homework* and it'd still apply here.  You've done a good job showing the setup, just show some SQL and you'll probably get some real quick help.

Comment: @vol7ron I tried on multiple queries, so should i post them all ?

Comment: Just one or two that you think were close.  Using http://sqlfiddle.com is also very helpful for the contributors in the community that are trying to help.

Comment: Unit Price and Billing Rate are nowhere to be found in your question which is why an example of how you've attempted to solve this problem is extremely helpful.

Comment: @user3289372 Sorry I added Product table. Forgot to add it earlier

Comment: In time, those id prefixes will drive you nuts. Likewise for the column prefixes - 'emp', etc.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.orderNumber,
       ordDate,
       salesPerson,
       SUM(price * quantity) as totalProductAmount,
       SUM(hours * billingRate) as totalInstallationAmount
from ORDERS o
join PRODLINE pl on pl.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
join PRODUCT p on p.productCode = pl.prodCode
join INSTLINE il on il.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
join INSTALLATION i on i.installationType = il.instType
group by o.orderNumber, ordDate, salesPerson
```

**Edit:** Answer to your second question.

```
select branchNumber,
       branchName,
       revenueTarget,
       SUM((price * quantity) + (hours * billingRate)) as revenueAttained
from BRANCH b
join EMPLOYEE e on e.empBranch = b.branchNumber
join ORDERS o on o.salesPerson = e.employeeID
join PRODLINE pl on pl.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
join PRODUCT p on p.productCode = pl.prodCode
join INSTLINE il on il.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
join INSTALLATION i on i.installationType = il.instType
group by branchNumber, branchName, revenueTarget
```

Comment: Why group by o.orderNumber, ordDate, salesPerson and not just group by o.orderNumber?

Comment: Can you please explain how are you getting the results ?

Comment: You will get an error if you have any columns in your `select` statement not contained in a `group by` clause or an aggregate function, like `SUM`.

Comment: Can I calculate sum of totalProductAmount and totalInstallationAmount ?

Answer (score 0):

Branch Totals:

```
select
     e.EMPBRANCH,
     b.BRANCHNAME, 
     b.REVENUETARGET,
     SUM(price * quantity) as BranchTotalProductAmount,
     SUM(hours * billingRate) as BranchTotalInstallationAmount
   from ORDERS o
   join PRODLINE pl 
     on pl.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   join PRODUCT p 
     on p.productCode = pl.prodCode
   join INSTLINE il 
     on il.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
   join INSTALLATION i 
    on i.installationType = il.instType
   join EMPLOYEE e 
    on e.EMPLOYEEID = o.SALESPERSON
   join BRANCH b 
    on b.BRANCHNUMBER = e.EMPBRANCH      
 GROUP BY e.EMPBRANCH, b.BRANCHNAME, b.REVENUETARGET
 HAVING b.REVENUETARGET < SUM(price * quantity) + SUM(hours * billingRate)
```

Comment: We dont need all results, but only the branch number, branch name, revenue_target, and the revenue_generated for each branch that fails to meet its revenue_target.

Comment: I want solution for second query

Comment: Please see revised answer